# How to improve this simple code by reducing the number of "if" statements?

Tags: java, object, if-statement

I am new to Java and am writing a simple code for a class assignment. Here it is:

```
public class Digit {

    int value;
    int end;


public Digit(int numSystem, int value) {

    this.end = numSystem;
    this.value = value;

}

public int getValue(){
    return value;
}

public boolean increment(){
    while (value < end){
        value +=1;
    }
        if(value == end){
            value = 0;
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }

        }

public String toString(){

    if (value < 9){

        return(String.valueOf(value));
    }
    if(value == 10){
        return("A");

    }
    if(value ==11){
        return("B");
    }
    if(value == 12){
        return("C");
    }
    if(value == 13){
        return("D");
    }
    if(value == 14){
        return("E");
    }
    if(value == 15){
        return("F");
    }
    if(value == 16){
        return("G");
    }
    if(value == 17){
        return("H");
    }
    if(value == 18){
        return("I");
    }
    if(value == 19){
        return("J");
    }
    if(value == 20){
        return("K");
    }
    if(value == 21){
        return("L");
    }
    if(value == 22){
        return("M");
    }
    if(value == 23){
        return("N");
    }
    if(value == 24){
        return("O");
    }
    if(value == 25){
        return("P");
    }
    if(value == 26){
        return("Q");
    }
    if(value == 27){
        return("R");
    }
    if(value == 28){
        return("S");
    }
    if(value == 29){
        return("T");
    }
    if(value == 30){
        return("U");
    }
    if(value == 31){
        return("V");
    }
    if(value == 32){
        return("W");
    }
    if(value == 33){
        return("X");
    }
        if(value ==34){

        return("Y");
    }
    else{
        return("Z");
    }


}


}
```

Now, I figured that the "toString()" method looks horrible. I was thinking of ways that I can do the same thing, but make it more efficient. So, I figured I can make an ArrayList to hold the values of "value", and then loop through it and assign it a letter. Maybe that is a good idea?

If so, how would I do it? Because every time I try I get an error.

Thank you for your time everyone!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think this would be better on code review

Comment: A little on design: the best method is to use a mapping between chars and their values (hash, dict, whatever the language calls it), so that you need not worry about the transformation and can simply call `varMap[charVar]` to get what you need. But consider that such mapping *exists already* (although implicitly) in the form of the ordinal value of every character. Thus, I suggest you try the answer given by @assylias, that's the **right way** to do it.

Answer (score 9):

You could simplify it with:

```
public String toString(){
    if (value <= 9) return String.valueOf(value);
    else if (value >= 10 && value <= 35) return "" + (char) ('A' + value - 10);
    else return "Z";
}
```

Note that in your code `toString` returns `Z` if `value == 9` which is probably an error.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an array in the start, and in your ToString you would just look up in the array

```
public String toString(){
    return arr[value];
}
```

Needless to say, you will have to have an array with the values

```
public class Digit {
    static String[] arr = {"0","1",...,"A","B",..."Z"};
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statements.

This piece of code also does the job

```
public String toString(){
    if (value < 9){
        return String.valueOf(value);
    } else {
        // Create a char array with values from a to z
        char[] chars = new char[26];
        int currentChar = 97;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
            chars[i] = (char) currentChar;
            currentChar++;
        }
        return chars[value - 10];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment can be reduced to:

```
public boolean increment(){
    while (value < end){
        value +=1;
    }

    value = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashMap and then you can store pairs of ints with their corresponding characters. You can then retrieve the charscter by using `myMap.get(30)` for example, that's the big if statement for the character values covered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the int to a char. 'A' is 65, so your input value + 55 would be your ASCII char.